# How to tell Docker my VBOX disk was size increased?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I have a VirtualBox Ubuntu machine running Docker. My disk size was 200GB and I was without any space left.

So I've decided to increase the disk space. After that I can confirm the disk was increased using GPARTED but my Docker still "thinking" the disk is 200GB in size and all my containers is running out of space.

How can I tell Docker that my disk have more space now?

Comment: Does `df` think the disk is larger?  If you run `docker info`, what storage driver is it using?  (If it's `overlay2` you don't have to do anything; if it's `devicemapper` this is tricky, but has probably already been addressed on SO somewhere.)

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
The answer is not only in Docker. My VirtualBox guest machine still thinking the disk is in old size too. Using lsblk can confirm the root "/" size was not changed.

So, to tell VIrtualBox guest Ubuntu about the disk size increase, you must

```
pvs
pvresize /dev/sda5
check the volume name using lsblk and then
lvextend -l+100%FREE /dev/<YOURS_VOL_NAME>-vg/root

Now lsblk tell me the correct size.
```

Now the Docker solution involves delete all instances, images, volumes and etc. It was this way for me but I don't know if I mess something or not. BE ADVISED anyway.

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
nano /etc/docker/daemon.json  <<-- May need to create a new one
rm -rf /var/lib/docker        <<-- YOU WAS WARNED !
sudo systemctl start docker
```

This is the /etc/docker/daemon.json content:

```
{
        "storage-driver": "devicemapper",
        "storage-opts": [
                "dm.basesize=750G"  <<-- PUT YOUR DISK SIZE HERE
        ]
}
```

I must confess don't know very well what I've done here but at least it worked. If you know better feel free to comment or edit.